# Help Solving a differential system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I'm stuck on a problem. In my vehicle dynamics class we have a problem to solve for rise time of x in the 2 given differential equations given here. Where s(t) is the steering angle as a function of time and it is a 30 degree step input.

$$\begin{cases}
m \dot{y}+a_1 x+a_2 y&=&b_1 s(t)\\
I\dot{x}+a_3 x+a_4 y&=&b_2 s(t)\end{cases}$$

I'm trying to get the plot of the response in Matlab (2007 version) but I am just returning for my Masters after 6 years and I haven't used Matlab in that time. I don't remember at all what to do and I've been searching all night and anything I found to try isn't working. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: See [this page](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) for help using the ode45 function in Matlab. It has examples that you can use as a guide. Mathworks provides a fairly extensive treatment of the inbuilt Matlab functions.

Comment: You know that a frequent (not compulsory) step in solving a differential equation or differential system is to find the homogeneous solution (by setting RHS to zero). In this case, this "homogeneous solution" is obtained by using matrix exponentials (Matlab function expm).

Comment: @ BradK2fan : Can you express "a 30 degree step input" in terms of standard mathematical function (not physical).